# Multiple Display Problem when one is off

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have 3 monitors (two of them are 4K TVs) connected to a desktop pc.

I don't need one of the TVs all the time, so I keep it off from time to time. If I turn on the computer while that TV is off; Ubuntu makes it the primary display, and every window I open ends up in that screen. I have to turn on that TV, move all the windows to another display, open display settings, pick the other tv as primary.

Is there a way to make Ubuntu ignore the TV when it is not working?

Hardware: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X  + Gigabyte X570 I AORUS PRO + GeForce GTX 1650

Comment: If Ubuntu is detecting the TV as a connected monitor when it's off, it's not going to be able to tell between when it's on or off, I'm afraid.

Comment: I guess something gets triggered when it is off, and it thinks the TV is On while it is Off and makes it primary